# Как создать имя файла с расширением .conf на основе имени файла с расширением .jar в ansible

Tags: python, unix, ansible, ansible-playbook

Уважаемые знатоки, подскажите пожалуйста, как создать конфигурационный файл с тем же именем что и jar-архив, но без расширения .jar с помощью ansible?

Содержимое директории:

```
application.yml   test-abc-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Сначала я ищу рабочей в директории jar архив. Затем, получив имя джарника создаю кофигурационный файл с точно таким же именем.

```
  - name: get jar name   
    find:
      paths: "{{ working_dir }}"
      patterns: 
        - "*.jar"
      file_type: file
    register: get_jar_name
    tags: update 

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ get_jar_name.files }}"
    tags: update

  - name: create conf file
    file:
      path: "{{ item.path  }}.conf"
      owner: "{{ user }}"
      group: "{{ user_group }}"
      state: touch
    with_items: "{{ get_jar_name.files }}"
    tags: update
```

В итоге файл создается с именем test-abc-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.conf. Как мне удалить из имени конфига .jar расширение?
PS: в регулярках не силен от слова совсем(
Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62443273/5741205

Comment: Вам надо в строке `test-abc-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.conf` найти подстроку `jar`?

Comment: На основе полученного имени архива test-abc-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar создать файл, но уже с расширеним .conf, т.е. test-abc-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.conf

Comment: может можно как-то выдернуть ".jar" из имени во время выполнения get jar name в моём примере, а в create conf file он, возможно, попадет уже без расширения в виде test-abc-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
соответственно создатся файл с нужным мне именем test-abc-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт, обновил path до вида:

```
  - name: create conf file
    file:
      path: "{{ (( item.path | splitext )[:-1] | join('.')) }}.conf"
      owner: "{{ user }}"
      group: "{{ user_group }}"
      state: touch
    with_items: "{{ get_jar_name.files }}"
    tags: update
```